# Fix the position of the snippet editor (or disable page scrolling)

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Is it possible to fix the position of the snippet editor (or disable the page scrolling in the background)? There are many times when I'm scrolling within the "Results" pane and I inadvertently start scrolling on the dark background, scrolling the editor out of the viewport window.

Answer (score 1):

I 100% agree with the occasional clunkiness of the Stack Snippet editor.

Until this is fixed, you can add a user style to make the position `fixed` instead of `absolute`.  Just add the following code to your user styles:

```css
.popup.popup-snippet {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 2.5% !important;
  left: 2.5% !important;
}
```

If you use Stylish, here's a quick User Style I wrote that will automatically apply across the various Stack Exchange domains:

https://userstyles.org/styles/114209/stack-snippet-editor-scrolling-fix