# Code snippet editor doesn't resize and center when developer tools are opened

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I think the **Javascript/HTML/CSS Snippets**, aka the **Runnable Code Snippets** aka the **Stack Snippets** are a great addition, but there is one 'feature' in it which annoys me: 
It doesn't resize or move when the content window is resized or -most common use case- when the developer tools are opened while the snippet editor is open.

[image: Incorrectly sized and/or centered]

So, the steps I've followed quite some times now are:

- I'm typing an answer,
- I open the editor to add a snippet,
- I open the developer tools (F12) to check the console, because something is not yet working in my snippet,
- Position is foobar and I cannot see my code properly anymore,
- I have to save/close the snippet and re-open it to continue working,
- I'm like  :'(

It seems the editor is opened in some container/lightbox that doesn't properly scale. If I inspect it, it shows me this (alignment mine)

```
<div class="popup popup-snippet esc-remove" 
     style="display: block; padding: 0px; 
            width: 95%; height: 95%; text-align: left; position: absolute; 
            top: 681px; 
            left: calc(50% - 905px); 
            z-index: 1001; background: white;">
```

My suggestion is to change it to:

```
<div class="popup popup-snippet esc-remove" 
     style="display: block; padding: 0px; 
            width: 95%; height: 95%; 
            position: fixed; 
            top: 2.5%; left: 2.5%; 
            z-index: 1001; background: white;">
```

This code contains no more fixed values (which are apparently determined through Javascript on opening the editor), so it's more portable.

In addition to solving the sizing (the editor just stays inside the visible area), it also solves the positioning that was proposed in "[Fix the position of the snippet editor (or disable page scrolling)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287669/fix-the-position-of-the-snippet-editor-or-disable-page-scrolling)" in March, by keeping the editor in a fixed position. The page underneath still scrolls, though, so you may have to block that, or jump back to the answer when closing the snippet editor (nice to have).

I must admit I'm not a web developer, so someone should probably review this, and maybe make some improvements and make sure it works good enough on all platforms (I'm using Chrome on Windows), but anyway, I would love to have this fixed, because to me it's the biggest nuisance when using Stack Snippets.

Comment: Huh. I never would've noticed this- I have all my dev tools set to open in a new window.

Comment: Then it's probably not an issue. Mine are docked. But it's not just when opening the dev tools. The editor just doesn't respond to any resizing. Or well, it doesn but incorrectly. It is always positioned at `50% - HalfTheOriginalScreenSizeMinusALittleOrSomething`, which is just incorrect, and unnecessarily complex in this case.

Comment: Oh, most of my coworkers have theirs docked too. I'm the only programmer I know that prefers a new window for dev tools. :) But it's still worth bringing up- Might have been a test-case the team didn't notice. (I'm sure if it is it just didn't cross their mind that people might open the editor, then resize the screen for any reason, such as the poor programmer with only one monitor who has something to add to the editor in another program and has to resize to see both easily.)