# Stack Snippets layout is broken

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

The console output is now by default visible in the snippet, which is especially blocking in the inline view of the snippet. Six lines of output, and nearly all of my snippet is gone. 
[image: Console output blocking the actual snippet]

It looks like you attempted a very, very elaborate workaround for [the issue of the poorly resizing snippet window](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309714/code-snippet-editor-doesnt-resize-and-center-when-developer-tools-are-opened), which is still not fixed. With a two line fix of CSS, almost every developer could just use the 'normal' console window if desired.

Having an extra console output could be a nice option, but mostly not necessary, and I think it shouldn't be on by default (and at least it shouldn't be blocking like this).

Btw, if your screen is only a bit smaller, stuff starts flowing all over each other. Use console label is not tied to the checkbox, close button moves down, and the code is on top of the buttons. No big problems, since usually a screen won't be that small, but again something that should be quite easy to fix:

[image: Layout bork bork]

Answer (score 1):

First, let me clarify something. This change wasn't motivated by [the bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309714/code-snippet-editor-doesnt-resize-and-center-when-developer-tools-are-opened) you referenced. It was motivated by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/159427), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279053/159427), and many other posts, i.e.:

> The community has been looking for a standard, acceptable means of demo'ing javascript output... and while we should be using `console.log()` and associated methods, people have fallen to using `alert()`, `document.write()`, etc... because they manage to provide immediate output to the reader by taking advantage of the snippet results window.

So, the team (thankfully) implemented a [virtual console](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console).

Keep in mind that you can very easily disable the virtual console for your particular snippet if it's interfering with your UI. I understand that you disagree with *having* to, so let's consider our options...

- Do nothing but persist your preference for `enabled`/`disabled`
- Disable the console by default, leaving the users to explicitly include it
- Disable the console by default, detect the use of console methods on saving (or the first time *running* in editmode) the snippet, and prompt the user to add the console:
  [image]
- Maybe add a tab for expanding/collapsing the console.

Comment: I think most of those are good options. To me I think the tab is the best. But actually I think it is solving a problem that doesn't exist. If people can provide output by using document.write or by adding content to an element, why isn't that okay? And if they choose to use the console there already is an window in most browsers to view that output.